# How to send data from UI, using doInBackground?

Tags: android, user-interface, tcpclient

I'm very new to android. I wanted to build client/server application, where client is running android and Server is running Java.

Clients code

```
package com.example.android;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

static String line= "works";
private MyTask mt;
private EditText nameField;
private TextView nameView;
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
    nameField =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.FirstInputField);
    nameView =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.DisplayText);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);   

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {               

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mt=new MyTask();
                mt.execute();

            }
        });
}

private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void>

{
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {

    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


        Socket s;
        try {
            s = new Socket ("172.17.20.42", 8888);
            ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            ObjectInputStream ios=new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            oos.writeObject(line);              
            oos.close();
            ios.close();    
            s.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       



        return null;
    }

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;


}
```

}

This program works fine, but the problem is , that I'm sending static String.

**doInBackground** method does not have access to UI thread. The question is "How to send a strings, that are typed in UI?"

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void>
{
    String line;
    public MyTask(String line) {
        this.line = line;
    }
```

Then in `onCreate()`:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    mt=new MyTask(nameView.getText().toString());
    mt.execute();
}
```

Note: This is not the most efficient or memory-saving method as you instantiate a new `MyTask` object for each line that is sent, but is the method that demands less changes in your code as it is now.

Comment: Thanks. Instead of nameView should be nameField

Answer (score 0):

In the on click of your button pass nameView.getText() to the MyTask, either in the constructor or the execute() method (will require you to accept the parameter as String... string and read it as string[0])

Answer (score 0):

Make first generic parameter of MyTask of type String:

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void>

{
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {

    }


@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

    String stringToSend = params[0];

    Socket s;
    try {
        s = new Socket ("172.17.20.42", 8888);
        ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        ObjectInputStream ios=new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        oos.writeObject(stringToSend);              
        oos.close();
        ios.close();    
        s.close();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       

    return null;
}
```

And pass the string parameter through `execute`:

```
mt.execute(new String[1] {nameField.getText().toString()});
```